# Why am I getting a "Not Found" Error when I call the DocuSign API using the docusign-esign npm package?

Tags: javascript, docusignapi

I have a google cloud function running on my local host and I have hosted a function that is supposed to receive `json`data from a client side application. I am using Post Man for testing of course. When I call the function endpoint, all the code executes well up until a point when I actually call the a function in the `docusign-esign` npm module.

The function is `createEnvelope()`. I call it and pass it an `apiAccountID` and `envelopeDefinition` object. I call the function within a `try` block and it catches an error. The error it returns is `Not Found`.

My code is shown below.

```
// function to call the e-signature api
const eSignFunc = async (basePath, accessToken, data) => {

 let dsApiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
 dsApiClient.setBasePath(basePath);
 dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
 let envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApiClient);

 // Step 1. Make the envelope requestuest body
 try {
   let envelope = makeEnvelope(data);

   // Step 2. call Envelopes::create API method
   // Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
   let results = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(dsConfig.apiAccountId, {
     envelopeDefinition: envelope,
   });
   let envelopeId = results.envelopeId;

   console.log(`Envelope was created. EnvelopeId ${envelopeId}`);
   if (results.status == "sent") {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
 } catch (error) {
   console.log("DS API CALL FAILED: " + error);
   return false;
 }
};
```

The arguments `basePath` , `accessToken` , and `data` contain data from preceeding function calls that serialize the data and validate that all the information is correct after which they call the `eSignFunc` shown above.

My problem is that the function executes and puts out the following error

`DS API CALL FAILED: Error: Not Found`

As you might have noticed that is printed out because of the 4th last line in the code above

My Question is: Why am I getting `Not Found`. I have done some reading in the DocuSign Developer docs and I have found out that it means that `The Resource doesn't exist`.

I just don't know which resource they are talking about. I am not trying to `get` something from the `API` rather I want to create a new resource

I have cross checked almost everything and I have seen everything is really consistent. This should be a small issue. I just need some help to understand what is going on please..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It almost looks like that's the app interpreting a 404.

It's hard to say without having your accountId (please don't post it here), but my first guess would be that there's something off with your basepath. Sometimes we do see customers when switching from an OAuth flow to sending via eSignature that the basepath isn't updated or it's pointing to the wrong environment. In terms of basepaths for Demo / Production it should be similar to this:

Demo:
OAuth: https://account-d.docusign.com
eSig:  https://demo.docusign.net/restapi

Production:
OAuth: https://account.docusign.com
eSig: https://{endpoint}.docusign.net/restapi

Note that Endpoint corresponds to the server that your account is housed on. You can see which specific endpoint you need to target by going to DocuSign.com > Settings > Apps and Keys.

If this doesn't help solve it go ahead and send me an email to matt.king@docusign.com -- we can have a support ticket opened for you and have a look in our system logs to see if anything is standing out.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually realised it was a problem with the endpoint. I got the solution by looking at the API reference and getting the right endpoint for my api call.